# Trying to push to GitHub

Tags: git, github

There is an existing repo on GitHub. I have then coded a project locally, and am trying to `push` to the remote branch `my_branch`.

I get the following:

```
$ git push -u origin my_branch
To github.com:xxxx/richard-m-xxxx.git
 ! [rejected]        my_branch -> my_branch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:xxxx/richard-m-xxxx.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

It says that my local branch (`my_branch`) is behind the remote branch. I have tried `git pull`, but it looks up to date.

```
$ git pull
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> my_branch
```

Please can someone advise me on the steps to `push` my project to the remote branch `my_branch` please?

Thank you.

Update

I also try the following unsuccessfully:

```
$ git pull origin my_branch
From github.com:xxxx/richard-m-xxxx
 * branch            my_branch  -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Then again:

```
$ git push origin my_branch
To github.com:xxxx/richard-m-xxxx.git
 ! [rejected]        my_branch -> my_branch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:xxxx/richard-m-xxxx.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: I would double check your are pushing from the correct directory. Try cd to another dir and then back. 

If that doesnt work git stash your changes, sync with remote, reapply changes with git stash pop, then try to push

Answer (score -3):

I found the solution here: https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/How-to-deal-with-quot-refusing-to-merge-unrelated-histories-quot/td-p/12619

```
git pull --allow-unrelated-histories origin my_branch
```